# Android animations are not used from RTL folders (ldrtl)

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, android-resources, android-navigation

When I switch my app language and layout direction to RTL, it doesn't affect animations.
I have such files: 
**anim/slide_in_from_end.xml**,

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300" />
```

**anim-ldrtl/slide_in_from_end.xml** (mirrored)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300" />
```

[image] 
Other resources (drawables etc) are used from RTL folders as expected, all layouts are right-to-left too.

**P.S** For some reason animations work as expected when "Force RTL layout" is enabled in developer options or System language is RTL.

Comment: UPD. Issue is reproducible for cases, when system manages animation by itself (Activity, DialogFragment etc.)

Comment: I am seeing the same problem, but have too many Activity to do manual check. Hope you had found a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

UPD.
Issue is reproducible for cases, when system manages animation by itself (Activity, DialogFragment etc.)

So the only solution I've found is to manually check current LayoutDirection and then set an animations (left and right).

```
overridePendingTransition(
    if (isLtr()) {
       R.anim.slide_in_from_right
    } else {
       R.anim.slide_in_from_left
    },
    android.R.anim.fade_out
)

fun Context.isLtr(): Boolean {
    return TextUtilsCompat.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(resources.configuration.locale) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
}
```

P.S The best soultion will be moving to Single-Activity architecture, so there won't be problems with animating Fragment's animations.